# Is there a way to embed a PDF document on a webpage and at the same time disabling download

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

We have a website where there are multiple PDF's available for the user. We have to restrict the user from downloading the PDF's. I Would prefer solution in Javascript/HTML

We tried multiple ways to Disable PDF download with javascript, But seems with update in chrome browser disabling dowload of PDF is not working. Chrome is using inbuild plugin pdf-viewer to  display PDF in browser window. pdf-viewer is not supporting the disable download feature.

Comment: Use a format that is not pdf then avoid the Chrome plugin.

Comment: The truth is that viewing a file also downloads it. So downloading for viewing or saving cannot be distinguished by the webserver. Even if you perfectly prevent saving the PDF, users could just take screenshots of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply certain techniques to make it difficult for users to download the PDFs.

Because it's impossible to completely prevent determined users from downloading the files if they have access to them.

You can make it more difficult for users to download the PDF files by using techniques like embedding the PDF within the webpage using iframes, converting the PDF to images, or using PDF viewers that do not expose download functionality.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We have embeded PDF in iframe. In iFrame also you can download PDF. Could you suggest any PDF viewer which do not expose download functionality.

Comment: There is a popular one named as PDF.js library. I need to see how to do it without having  download functionality.